# how to work with a column name which has a space?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I have a column name "user id" now when I use it in insert or... all of the following tries gave me syntax error:

```
insert into mytbl('user id',..
insert into mytbl(['user id'],..
insert into mytbl([user id],..
```

How can I solve this problem?

Please let me knbow if you need more clarification

Thanks

Comment: change it to something without a space. it may preserve your sanity

Comment: yes like : `user_id` or `userid` or something else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it in ticks:

```
INSERT INTO mytbl(`user id`,..
```

to reffer to a table use

```
    tbl1.`user name`
```

Comment: Thanks man! You solved it! I will mark it as solved :)

Comment: and if I want to refer to it with a table name, would it be tbl1.[`user name`] or tbl1.`user name`.?

Comment: This solution solves your immediate problem, but down the road you will be sad at having to deal with all the spaces, and how many inadvertent errors you make.